# UICollection View Custom Header not showing Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Please help, I've been trying to figure out why my code doesnt work. What I want to do is to have a custom header for my collection view but it seems that the class that I registered doesn't seem to trigger.
It doesn't even show the red box. It just shows a cyan blank background

What am I doing wrong?

[image: snapshot]

Below are my codes:

```
class VideoDetailController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private let headerId = "headerId"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        collectionView?.register(VideoDetailHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)

        navigationItem.title = "Hello!"
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! VideoDetailHeader
        return header
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width,height:170)
    }
}


class VideoDetailHeader: BaseCell {    
    override func setupViews() {
        print("Setting up...")
        super.setupViews()
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

**BaseCell is UICollectionViewCell**

Comment: try this **self.mycollectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "keyname", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerID")**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! So how can I connect the VideoDetailHeader Class if I replace with UINib(nibName: "keyname", bundle: nil)? And what would be the keyname?

Comment: keyname is name of your nib here

Comment: Yup, I tried it like this:

collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: VideoDetailHeader.nibName, bundle: nil),forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)

Comment: then:
static var nibName : String    { get { return "headerNIB"} }
still doesn't work :(

Comment: You forgot collectionView?.delegate = self collectionView?.dataSource = self

Comment: Hi @ΒασίληςΔ. actually I stopped that line first since I just want to know if my VideoDetailHeader class is being registered. It seems that I has been registered isn't showing since I'm calling UICollectionViewLayout instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayout :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the above codes work:
The only issue is that when I call this view controller, I used:
let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
instead of :
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()